# zf3 virtual host redirects to the wrong page

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, zend-framework3

I configured zend framework 3 through composer on remote debian server. I added virtual host to etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf like below but it shows just "It works!" page instead of zf3 public. Do anyone knows hos to solve it?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName zfapp.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/skeleton-application/public
<Directory /var/www/mysite/skeleton-application/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Just checking : restarted apache?

Comment: yes, and `a2enmod mysite` worked to solve `500 Internal server` problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

Have you enabled the site on the remote Debian server. To enable the site you should use `a2ensite mysite`

The **ServerName** directive should correspond the the HTTP hostname in the HTTP request. When you are dereferencing a URL on the remote server, the hostname part in the browser should correspond with the ServerName. It is unlikely you are using zfapp.localhost since most OS's have reserved host entries of 127.0.0.1 for any localhost derivative.

Comment: `a2ensite mysite` is not worked for me. so you mean I can't access zfapp.localhost from my computer?

Comment: Is Apache installed on your local machine. It sounds like you are requesting URL's on you local computer not the remote Debian server

Comment: Yes for sure. BTW `http://some_ip:port/skeleton-application/public/` is giving `500 Internal Server Error` as well

Comment: `apachectl -V
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Sep 16 2016 10:02:24`